# Ich hoffte, sie würde sich schnell eingewöhnen

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anyone help to find out the difference between sich eingewöhnen and sich gewöhnen? All dictionaries I have tell that both have the same meaning!!

Comment: **Eingewöhnen** is getting accustomed to a new situation, place or group in which you stay for a long time. You could use *gewöhnen* for that purpose, too, but it has a ringing the situation, place or group is unpleasant. *Eingewöhnen* does not transport a judgment.

Comment: Also "gewöhnen" needs a noun ("sich an etwas gewöhnen") which is implied in "eingewöhnen".

Comment: Can sich "eingewöhnen" also mean to settle?

Comment: No, but *eingewöhnen* is a part of the process of relocating.

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/eingew%C3%B6hnen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"sich gewöhnen" heißt in vollständiger Form "sich **an etw/jmd** gewöhnen" ("to get used **to sb/sth**") und wird fast immer transitiv (=mit Objekt) benutzt.

> Ich habe mich schnell an die höheren Preise gewöhnt.
>    Ich kann mich immer noch nicht an seine neue Frisur gewöhnen.
>    Er hat sich daran gewöhnt, allein zu leben.

"sich eingewöhnen" heißt in vollständiger Form "sich **an/in etw** eingewöhnen" ("to settle in [**at sth**]") und hat einen spezielleren Objektkreis (etw = Arbeitsplatz, Lebensweise, neue Wohnung etc.), wird aber häufig intransitiv (=ohne Objekt) benutzt.

> Wie ist dein neuer Arbeitsplatz? Hast du dich eingewöhnt?
>    Hast du dich in deiner neuen Wohnung schon gut eingewöhnt?
>    Das Kind hat sich (im Kindergarten) eingewöhnt.